# jQuery script that indexes and redisplays images

Tags: jquery

This is most likely a basic question but as I'm a beginner with jQuery I'm lost. Please be gentle :)

I'm trying to build a script that indexes all image elements in a table, then on click clears the page, then redisplay those images in the cleared container. I've succeeded in clearing the page, but I'm having trouble making the indexed images reappear in the container.

```
   var images = $("table img");
   $("a").click(function(event){
        $("#canvas").html('');
        $(images).each(function(){
            // no good :(
            $("#canvas").add(this);
        }); 
    });
```

How can I make those images appear?

---

Update: Made it work.

```
var images = $("table img");
$("a").click(function(event){
    $("#canvas").html('');
    $(images).each(function(){
        $("#canvas").append(images)[idx];
    });
});
```

Comment: Post your solution as an answer and, when you're able, accept that. This allows the question to be marked as solved/answered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of "$("#canvas").add(this);" use this...

```
$("#canvas").append(this);
```

Comment: Got it, it was $("#canvas").append(images)[idx].outerHTML;
outerHTML prints the html code. I've updated the question.